# Delegating to a class method

Tags: ruby

Is it possible in Ruby to delegate to a class method of another class so to replace the method below?

```
def sugar(param)
  Klass.a_very_long_method_name(param)
end
```

I have tried to use `Forwardable`

```
   extend Forwardable
   def_delegator 'Klass.a_very_long_method_name', :sugar
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

I find myself to call `Klass.a_very_long_method_name` in many places and I'm trying to dry things up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
require 'forwardable'

class Klass
  def self.a_very_long_method_name(name)
    puts "Hi, #{name}"
  end
end

class Sugar
  extend Forwardable
  def_delegator Klass, :a_very_long_method_name, :verrry_long
end

s = Sugar.new
s.verrry_long "Sue"
  # Hi, Sue
```

In `def_delegator Klass, :a_very_long_method_name, :verrry_long`, `Klass` is the receiver of the message forwarding, `:a_very_long_method_name` is the message to be forwarded and `:verrry_long` is an alias of the message `:a_very_long_method_name`.

Comment: Thank for the reply. Enjoy your day.